# Automate saving attachments from email in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, attachments

I would like to automate the saving of an attachment for specific incoming emails in Outlook 2016 to my local computer. I looked at serveral sites, which mainly propose the use of VBA, but I get stuck at importing the script in Outlook. Older versions of Outlook did support a 'run a script' option in the Rule wizard, but the 2016 version does not. Are there other options to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

'run a script' option was removed since Outlook 2013. But we can create an `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules` registry value to bring back this option. You can refer to the MS Support Article: [How to control the rule actions to start an application or run a macro in Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191893/how-to-control-the-rule-actions-to-start-an-application-or-run-a-macro)